# Service Application in WSS 3.0 doesn't save password

Tags: wss

i'm trying to set service application account in WSS 3.0 for default application pool which hosts portal site.
But when i choose not to use default account and add another managed account, after the page refresh it shows me that this settings wasn't saved.

Still in IIS snap-in i see that application pool used credentials i put in CA.

Any information about this behaviour will be usefull.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are using WSS 3.0? The concept of managed account is new to SharePoint foundation 2010

Comment: Yes, it's WSS 3.0, not Foundation. Maybe i make a mistake in description, service account, not management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you find errors in your ULS logs that say "Access denied" or "unexpected error"? If so, check if your farm account has write permission on %windir%\tasks. You could also run psconfig, which will set the permissions for that account.